# Strange (?) behaviour while sorting CMFCListCtrl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a subclass of CMFCListCtrl that supports sorting, reading the documentation I have to implement
the virtual method:

```
virtual int OnCompareItems(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, int nColumn);
```

where lParam1 and lParam2 are params of some sort, specified when the list control is created.

Since I need an alphabetical sort I've inserted my rows in this way:

```
item.mask = LVIF_COLFMT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_TEXT;
for (nI = 0; nI ....)
{
    // UMASK, ITEM IDX, TEXT, STATE 1, STATE 2, IMAGE IDX, LPARAM
    m_lstMateriali.InsertItem(item.mask, nI, _T("   "), 0, 0, SelezionaIcona(itIM->m_bSelez, itIM->m_eStatus), nI);
    strQnt.Format(_T("%d"), itIM->m_nIdBolla);
    m_lstMateriali.SetItemText(nI, 1, strQnt);
    m_lstMateriali.SetItemText(nI, 2, itIM->m_strCodMater);
    m_lstMateriali.SetItemText(nI, 3, itIM->m_strDescrMater);
    m_lstMateriali.SetItemText(nI, 4, itIM->m_strColore);
    strQnt.Format(_T("%d"), itIM->m_nDaTag);
    m_lstMateriali.SetItemText(nI, 5, strQnt);
    m_lstMateriali.SetItemData(nI, nI);
}
```

At this point, my Subclass sorting method:

```
virtual int OnCompareItems(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, int nColumn)
{
    int     nCol_1;             ///< 
    int     nCol_2;             ///< 
    CString strCol_1;           ///< 
    CString strCol_2;           ///< 

    strCol_1 = GetItemText(lParam1, nColumn);
    strCol_2 = GetItemText(lParam2, nColumn);
    switch (nColumn)
    {
    case 2:
        return strCol_1.Compare(strCol_2);
    }
}
```

works greatly. But now, because of sorting, my LPARAMs are no more correct since they represent the row number.
I then handled the header click notification, which happens **after** the sorting:

```
void CEliCUTK2SceltaMaterialiDlg::OnHdnItemclickLstSmListapezzi(NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult)
{
    int         nNumRig;
    CString     strCodMat;
    LPNMHEADER  phdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHEADER>(pNMHDR);
    LVITEM      item;

    nNumRig = m_lstMateriali.GetItemCount();
    memset(&item, 0, sizeof(LVITEM));
    item.mask = LVIF_PARAM;
    for (int nI = 0; nI < nNumRig; nI++)
    {
        item.iItem = nI;
        item.lParam = nI;
        m_lstMateriali.SetItem(&item);  // (1)
        strCodMat = m_lstMateriali.GetItemText(nI, 2);
        // bla bla about item data
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

it might be the worst practice, but for now it works pretty good: I set the new LPARAMs according with
the new row numbers. I also picked up text before and after point (1) to check if I updated the right 
row and everything seems fine: I got old param first and new param then.

What now: I clicked another time in the row header to sort descending and what I get? Everything scrumbled.
I decided to check some stuff and I added the following code:

```
void CEliCUTK2SceltaMaterialiDlg::OnLvnItemchangedLstSmListapezzi(NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult)
{
    int             nSot, nTip;
    CString         strID;
    DWORD_PTR       dwID;
    LPNMLISTVIEW    pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    LVITEM          item;

    if (pNMLV->uNewState == 3)
    {
        dwID = m_lstMateriali.GetItemData(pNMLV->iItem);
        memset(&item, 0, sizeof(LVITEM));
        item.mask = LVIF_PARAM;
        item.iItem = pNMLV->iItem;
        m_lstMateriali.GetItem(&item);
        strID.Format(_T("PARAM: %ld."), item.lParam);
        AfxMessageBox(strID);
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

restarted the program, sort the list again and clicking the **first** row (after having checked again that the new LPARAMs are correct)
I got the message:

```
PARAM: 10.
```

while I should get:

```
PARAM: 0.
```

10 is the old position. Is there something that I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: it was in

```
// bla bla about item data
```

where I update the data with the member:

```
SetItemData(int, DWORD_PTR);
```

according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/936147y4.aspx ItemData is actually LPARAM value specified in LVITEM structure.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you want to store in lParam is something that will allow you to get back to the data that you used to populate the list with, or a pointer to a structure that contains the data to compare.  Putting in an index will work if you have a parallel CList or std::list collection (or CArray or std::vector) that does not change it's order during the lifetime of the CListCtrl.

After things are sorted or during insertion, item 10 in the list might have an lParam of 2 in your example.  You want to use the "2" to index into the original data source (a CList, CArray, record set, or something...) and then get the data there and use your comparison on the original data.  Because, when you sort, the indexes in lParam will not be the same as the index in the CListCtrl (or CMFCListCtrl).

You can allocate a structure of all the data you need for your compare and store it in the lParam member.  (In some MFC classes you use SetItemDataPtr).  To clean up the data, handle the LVN_DELETEITEM message.

Comment: Well, this is what I did in another class similar to this. Anyway: you're telling me that once I set the lParam there's no way to change it unless I delete item and put it back?

Comment: You can change it and do whatever you want.  However, I don't think you should change it.  I think you should set it once and have it refer to the original data somehow, and then in your compare function, use the lParam to reference the original data and then return a value based on the comparison with the original data.

Comment: Fine, that's it, but then, if I can change it (best or worst practice I don't mind) why I got it reset to 10 if I set it to 0?

Comment: It seems like you are insisting in storing the index as the lParam (or dwData, they're the same) of each item. That's definitely a bad idea. It forces you to do a lot of bookkeeping, that will probably leave some bug somewhere. As @JoeWillcoxson said, you should store something that identifies the item you are storing, no matter where it is in the list. It can be a pointer to the actual item, an index in another list where you keep the items, etc.  Your CListCtrl is just a view on your data. The dwData field is a way to get to the actual data, or the data you need to sort it, in this case.

Comment: @IssamTP Put another way, if you don't mind using worst practices, expect to get "strange" results